# Get title and body from drupal article

Tags: jquery-mobile, drupal

I'm trying to build a jQuery Mobile application containing pictures, title and body from my Drupal page. I can get the pictures from my Drupal article.
But how to get the title and body from the current article / node?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be trying to build the mobile app from scratch when you should really be starting with the [jQuery Mobile](https://drupal.org/project/jquerymobile) module/theme. It's a great base and will probably provide you with most of what you're looking for. [Here's a nice slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/attheshow/building-a-mobile-drupal-site) demoing how to go about starting this process.